# UnableToResolveError while running react native app

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on `react-native` app, for which I am using atom text editor. I am using this https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2017/1/Introducing-React-Navigation for navigation. I installed `react-navigation` as this says.

> npm install --save react-navigation

```
D:\React Native\Scheduled>npm install --save react-navigation
Scheduled@0.0.1 D:\React Native\Scheduled
`-- react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.7
  +-- clamp@1.0.1
  +-- hoist-non-react-statics@1.2.0
  +-- path-to-regexp@1.7.0
  | `-- isarray@0.0.1
  +-- react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill@1.3.0
  | `-- react-native-drawer-layout@1.3.0
  |   `-- react-native-dismiss-keyboard@1.0.0
  `-- react-native-tab-view@0.0.57
```

Hope it is installed successfully. Once it is done, I compiled a project which is successful.

```
D:\React Native\Scheduled>react-native run-android
Scanning 566 folders for symlinks in D:\React Native\Scheduled\node_modules (15m
s)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug)...
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-22' in inconsistent locati
on 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-googl
e-22-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-go
ogle_apis-google-22')
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent locati
on 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-googl
e-23-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-go
ogle_apis-google-23')
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-22' in inconsistent locati
on 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-googl
e-22-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-go
ogle_apis-google-22')
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23' in inconsistent locati
on 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-googl
e-23-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-go
ogle_apis-google-23')
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DA
TE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0433Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Google Nexus 6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 1440x2560
- 7.0' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.101 secs
Running C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.1
68.79.101:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on 192.168.79.101:5555 (C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Androi
d\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.79.101:5555 shell am start -n com.scheduled/
.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.scheduled/.MainActivity }

D:\React Native\Scheduled>
```

I am restarting `react-server` with this command, here I am getting a problem `UnableToResolveError`.

```
D:\React Native\Scheduled>react-native start
Scanning 566 folders for symlinks in D:\React Native\Scheduled\node_modules (15m
s)
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐

 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │

 │                                                                            │

 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │

 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │

 │  prefer.                                                                   │

 │                                                                            │

 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │

 │                                                                            │

 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   D:\React Native\Scheduled

Loading dependency graph...
React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `react/lib/React
ComponentWithPureRenderMixin` from `D:\React Native\Scheduled\node_modules\react
-navigation\src\views\Header.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in
these directories:
  D:\React Native\Scheduled\node_modules\react\lib
,   D:\React Native\node_modules\react\lib

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cache`
.
    at UnableToResolveError (D:/React Native/Scheduled/node_modules/react-native
/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:488:5)
    at p.catch.error (D:/React Native/Scheduled/node_modules/react-native/packag
er/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:366:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
Bundling `index.android.js`  85.5% (492/532), failed.
```

I am not sure what went wrong after installation of `react-navigation` it stuck, it was working before it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem with me. Just delete the code of 12 line(witch import `ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin` but not exist in react and never used) in `yourproject\node_modules\react-navigation\src\views\Header.js`  will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `react-native-router-flux` package in npm for routing in react-native.

link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux

Comment: Thanks! I want to use https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2017/1/Introducing-React-Navigation do you have an idea what went wrong ?

Comment: -  Delete node modules folder from your project directory.
- Then in your project directory  type this command  "npm install "  in command prompt .

Comment: After that enter  " npm install --save react-navigation "

Comment: Do I need to delete node modules every time for installing any package ?

Comment: Not Need @Williams if there is a problem in packages ,we have to remove node modules folder.

Comment: Your installed packages details are stored in package.json file. so if you run command " npm install " list of "dependencies" in package.json that would be install.

Comment: I deleted node modules then run this command `npm install` then `npm install --save react-navigation` however I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me more often and i couldn't find where is the problem but mostly when i use "babael" it happen.
rebuilding app will solve the issue .
and three step as react suggest you will be usful

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cache`
   .

Comment: I am on windows machine, I see there is no command `watchman`. How to install `watchman` on windows machine ?

Comment: BTW I deleted node modules then run this command `npm install` then `npm start --reset-cache` then `npm install --save react-navigation` however I am facing same issue.. I did not run `watchman`

Comment: sorry windows version currently not supported

Comment: before running npm install command make sure there's no process assign to react running on background if it does remove it by PID number

Comment: Yes, there is no process assigned to react, I followed above steps but still it did not resolve my issue :(